# What does the parameter in this formula in conditional formatting really do in excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

Below is a formula that takes a list of values in column AH and formats them if they appear in column K

=COUNTIF($AH$2:$AH$8,K2)>0

If I introduce K3 instead of K2, the coloring I chose misses its mark by one row. So if for example I have a value in K33 that exists in column AH, instead of it being formatted the way I want it to, K32 is formatted, even though the value in K32 is nowhere to be found in column AH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a formula and "applies to" range set for a conditional formatting condition it always works like this:

The formula is applied exactly "as is" to the **top left** cell in the `"applies to"` range but then adjusted (implicitly) for all other cells in that range, the same way it would adjust if dragged on the worksheet, so if you have this formula in conditional formatting

`=COUNTIF($AH$2:$AH$8,K2)>0`

.....and the "applies to" range is `K2:K100`, for example, then K2 will be formatted if K2 exists in the range AH2:AH8, K3 will be formatted if K3 exists in the range AH2:AH8, K4 will be formatted if K4 exists in the range AH2:AH8.....etc etc.

....but if you change the formula to use `K3` instead of `K2` then it only works if the "applies to" range is also changed (to begin at K3). If you don't change the "applies to" range then the formatting will be one row out as you describe.

Note that the formula that you apply in conditional formatting may not be the one that actually gets used in some circumstances:

1) If you select a range on the worksheet to be the applies to range, but the active cell isn't the top left cell of that range then the formula you enter will be adjusted as if you dragged it to the top left cell, e.g. if you apply this formula = A5="x" when you have C4:C7 selected and with C7 the active cell then the formula actually used is A2="x"

2) If you already have a conditional formatting condition set and then you change the "applies to" range then the formula might adjust based on that change

Comment: @pnuts I think there are two different things here. I believe what I said above is always correct. For a moment forget HOW the CF is set, just the result. If you look at a condition and it's set for "applies to" range B3:B7 but the formula says =B7="x" then it works as I said, =B7="x" is applied to B3, so it's formatted if B7="x", and B4 is formatted if B8="x" etc. Indeed how could it be otherwise? Once the CF has been set it's not possible to tell what the "active cell" was at the time....

Comment: .....but something odd does happen if the active cell is not the top left cell. If I select the same range B3:B7 and apply the same formula =B7="x", but B7 is active cell....then Excel actually changes the formula as if you dragged it from the active cell to the top left, in this case the formula changes to =B4="x", so I agree that the choice of active cell does affect the outcome. but only because it might change the formula. Once formula is set what I said in my answer applies

Comment: @pnuts OK, yes I agree - I ought to make a distinction between the formula actually being applied and the one the user enters - which might not always be the same thing! I'll edit my answer

Comment: @pnuts - it really is never mundane for me, I wouldn't be here otherwise! Always appreciate your insight and comments

Comment: BTW, when discussing conditional formatting I actually miss how it worked in Excel 2003. Although you were limited to 3 conditions, you could actually explicitly see which CF formula was being applied for each cell.....

Answer (score 0):

Your formula returns TRUE if the number of occurrences of the value in K2 in the range AH2:AH8 is greater than 0. In other words, it returns TRUE if the value in K2 is found somewhere in AH2:AH8. If you replace K2 with K3 then number of occurrences of the value in K3 will be compared with 0.

This kind of formula, i.e. one which returns FALSE or TRUE is commonly used for the purpose of conditional formatting. Let us say, you wish to colour cell K33 red if K2 is found in AH2:AH8. In that case you would use the formula in the conditional formatting of cell K33. As you see, the colour of cell K33 has nothing to do with the recurrence of its value in AH2:AH8.

Nor can an adjacent cell be coloured because you changed the reference to K2 in the formula. The formula determines the rule by which colouring is applied. The cell to which the rule will be applied is determined by where you place the formula.